# cntk.exe and associated dlls are 320 MB -- can my run-time be smaller?

Tags: dll, export, cntk

Everything working great with CNTK.  But, the folder containing cntk.exe and a bunch of DLLs is about 320 MB in size.   Can it be smaller?   Are there DLLs that I can safely leave out of my export which are dynamically linked so it will still work?  If so, how do I find which ones?  Has anyone figured out the minimal sized run-time stuff needed?  The NN I'm running is essentially AlexNet, if that matters.  Thanks!